# In Mongo, are unique indexes supported for sharded environments?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding, mongodb-indexes

We're exploring Mongo for a new website and we want to ensure no two users sign up with the same email address, so, a unique index on the email field is necessary.

Is this supported in a sharded Mongo environment? Mongo documentation states unique indexes are supported, but makes no mention of shards.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> You can use the `{unique: true}` option to ensure that the underlying
>   index enforces uniqueness so long as the unique index is a prefix of
>   the shard key. (note: prior to version 2.0 this worked only if the
>   collection is empty).

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding

This makes intuitive sense, as mongodb has no way of checking uniqueness across shards, unless the shard key gives you such cross-shard uniqueness guarantees "for free".

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. I just need to make the email field part of the shard key? What if my shard key is `lastname:1, email:1`, how can I ensure uniqueness is enforced only on `email` and not `lastname`?

Comment: If you did it that way, mongo would be able to assure that lastname was unique, but not e-mail.  If your shard key was reversed, then uniqueness of e-mail could be assured.  The unique index needs to be a prefix of the shard key, not just a subset.

Answer (score 0):

We do

```
if( $exists = $mongo_UserCollection->findOne( $desiredEmail ) )
{
    throw new User_Exception( 'Email address in use.' );
}
```